# How to select the first occurrence of a repeated item in sequence in a list using traditional python or using pandas/numpy/sciy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, pandas-groupby

Let's say there is a list 'series' which has some repeated elements at several index values. Is there a way to find the first occurrence of a repeated sequence of a number.

```
series = [2,3,7,10,11,16,16,9,11,12,14,16,16,16,5,7,9,17,17,4,8,18,18]
```

Return should be similar to [5,11,17,21] which are the index values of first occurrence for repeated sequences of [16,16] , [16,16,16] , [17,17] and [18,18]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one for performance using array-slicing, similar to [`@piRSquared's second solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46418523/3293881) but without any appending/concatenation -

```
a = np.array(series)
out = np.flatnonzero((a[2:] == a[1:-1]) & (a[1:-1] != a[:-2]))+1
```

Sample run -

```
In [28]: a = np.array(series)

In [29]: np.flatnonzero((a[2:] == a[1:-1]) & (a[1:-1] != a[:-2]))+1
Out[29]: array([ 5, 11, 17, 21])
```

**Runtime test** (for working solutions)

Approaches -

```
def piRSquared1(series):
    d = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(series) == 0)
    w = np.append(True, np.diff(d) > 1)
    return d[w].tolist()

def piRSquared2(series):
    s = np.array(series)
    return np.flatnonzero(
        np.append(s[:-1] == s[1:], True) &
        np.append(True, s[1:] != s[:-1])
    ).tolist()

def Zach(series):
    s = pd.Series(series)
    i = [g.index[0] for _, g in s.groupby((s != s.shift()).cumsum()) if len(g) > 1]
    return i

def jezrael(series):
    s = pd.Series(series)
    s1 = s.shift(1).ne(s).cumsum()
    m = ~s1.duplicated() & s1.duplicated(keep=False)
    s2 = m.index[m].tolist()
    return s2    

def divakar(series):
    a = np.array(series)
    x = a[1:-1]
    return (np.flatnonzero((a[2:] == x) & (x != a[:-2]))+1).tolist()
```

For the setup, we are simply tiling the sample input a number of times.

Timings -

Case #1 : Large set

```
In [34]: series0 = [2,3,7,10,11,16,16,9,11,12,14,16,16,16,5,7,9,17,17,4,8,18,18]

In [35]: series = np.tile(series0,10000).tolist()

In [36]: %timeit piRSquared1(series)
    ...: %timeit piRSquared2(series)
    ...: %timeit Zach(series)
    ...: %timeit jezrael(series)
    ...: %timeit divakar(series)
    ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 8.06 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 7.79 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 3.88 s per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 24.3 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 7.97 ms per loop
```

Case #2 : Much larger set (on top 2 solutions)

```
In [40]: series = np.tile(series0,1000000).tolist()

In [41]: %timeit piRSquared2(series)
1 loop, best of 3: 823 ms per loop

In [42]: %timeit divakar(series)
1 loop, best of 3: 823 ms per loop
```

Now, those two solutions differ only in the way appending is avoided in the latter one. Let's take a closer look at them and run on a smaller dataset -

```
In [43]: series = np.tile(series0,100).tolist()

In [44]: %timeit piRSquared2(series)
10000 loops, best of 3: 89.4 µs per loop

In [45]: %timeit divakar(series)
10000 loops, best of 3: 82.8 µs per loop
```

Thus, it reveals that the concatenation/append avoiding in the latter solution helps a lot when dealing with smaller datasets, but at much larger datasets, they become comparable.

Marginal improvement on larger dataset is possible with one concatenation there. Thus, the last step could be re-written as :

```
np.flatnonzero(np.concatenate(([False],(a[2:] == a[1:-1]) & (a[1:-1] != a[:-2]))))
```

Comment: Oh fine, we're competing on speed?  Lemme drag out `numba` :)  See my answer below.

Comment: @DanielF I thought OP were using pandas/numpy/scipy ;)

Comment: Who says cheaters never win?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed approach !

Answer (score 2):

You could use `shift`

```
In [3815]: s = pd.Series(series)

In [3816]: cond = (s == s.shift(-1))

In [3817]: cond.index[cond]
Out[3817]: Int64Index([5, 11, 12, 17, 21], dtype='int64')
```

Or, `diff`

```
In [3828]: cond = s.diff(-1).eq(0)

In [3829]: cond.index[cond]
Out[3829]: Int64Index([5, 11, 12, 17, 21], dtype='int64')
```

For list output use `tolist`

```
In [3833]: cond.index[cond].tolist()
Out[3833]: [5, 11, 12, 17, 21]
```

---

Details

```
In [3823]: s.head(10)
Out[3823]:
0     2
1     3
2     7
3    10
4    11
5    16
6    16
7     9
8    11
9    12
dtype: int64

In [3824]: cond.head(10)
Out[3824]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: need `[5, 11, 17, 21]`

Comment: I have tried this approach before I realize where the issue was. Let's say the repeating sequence is s= pd.Series(1,2,3,3,3). So if you shift by -1, you will have 2 `True`'s when run `cond = (s == s.shift(-1))` . But the return needs to be only the index `2` since that is the first occurrence of any repeating sequence

Answer (score 2):

**`np.diff` & `np.flatnonzero`**
This answer uses `np.diff` and tests for when that difference is zero.  At those points, we know we have duplication.  We use `np.flatnonzero` to give us the positions of where those differences are zero.  However, we only want the first position of consecutive differences.  So we use `np.diff` again to filter out only the first of the series of duplicates.  This time we use the results as a boolean mask.

```
d = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(series) == 0)
w = np.append(True, np.diff(d) > 1)
d[w]

array([ 5, 11, 17, 21])
```

---

**`np.flatnonzero`**
This is a superior answer in my opinion.  We build a boolean array evaluating when a value is equal to the next but not equal to the previous.  We leverage `np.flatnonzero` to tell us the positions of the `True` values.

I also find the symmetry of the answer appealing.

```
s = np.array(series)

np.flatnonzero(
    np.append(s[:-1] == s[1:], True) &
    np.append(True, s[1:] != s[:-1])
)

array([ 5, 11, 17, 21])
```

Comment: I think, OP is asking to return the consecutive dupe indexes.

Comment: @Zero fixed.  Thx for watching out (-:

Answer (score 2):

First create unique groups by `shift` with `cumsum` and then get mask for first duplicates and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = pd.Series([2,3,7,10,11,16,16,9,11,12,14,16,16,16,5,7,9,17,17,4,8,18,18])

s1 = s.shift(1).ne(s).cumsum()
m = ~s1.duplicated() & s1.duplicated(keep=False)
s2 = m.index[m].tolist()
print (s2)
[5, 11, 17, 21]
```

---

```
print (s1)
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      4
4      5
5      6
6      6
7      7
8      8
9      9
10    10
11    11
12    11
13    11
14    12
15    13
16    14
17    15
18    15
19    16
20    17
21    18
22    18
dtype: int32
```

---

```
print (m)
dtype: int32
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5      True
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11     True
12    False
13    False
14    False
15    False
16    False
17     True
18    False
19    False
20    False
21     True
22    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: A clever way of using `keep` argument in duplicated. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Since we appear to be competing on speed, and it's not likely anyone will beat Divakar / piRsquared without cheating around the `pandas`/`numpy`/`scipy` requirement, here's my `numba` solution:

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

@jit
def rpt_idx(s):
    out = []
    j = True
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == s[i+1]:
            if j:
                out.append(i)
                j = False
        else:
            j = True
    return out

rpt_idx(series)
Out: array([ 5, 11, 17, 21])
```

Probably totally overkill to pull out `jit` for such a trivial case, but it does give a big speedup

```
%timeit rpt_idx(series)
The slowest run took 10.50 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.99 µs per loop

%timeit divakar(series)
The slowest run took 7.73 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.5 µs per loop

series_ = np.tile(series,10000).tolist()

%timeit divakar(series_)
100 loops, best of 3: 20.1 ms per loop

%timeit rpt_idx(series_)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.84 ms per loop
```

Comment: Not anymore :)  Faster too.

Comment: Well upvote on admitting on the cheating part.. and somewhat on effort :)

Comment: IMHO, microsecond benchmarks are never good. And are we measuring this on 20 elements array? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can imitate Python's `itertools.groupby` simply enough, and group adjacent duplicates together.

```
>>> import pandas
>>> s = pandas.Series([2, 3, 7, 10, 11, 16, 16, 9, 11, 12, 14, 16, 16, 16, 5, 7, 9, 17, 17, 4, 8, 18, 18])
>>> for _, group in s.groupby((s != s.shift()).cumsum()):
...     if len(group) > 1:
...         print(group.index[0])
5
11
17
21
```

Or as a list:

```
>>> [g.index[0] for _, g in s.groupby((s != s.shift()).cumsum()) if len(g) > 1]
[5, 11, 17, 21]
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach. I am not sure why but @jezrael answer runs at 3x speed even though he used cumsum() function!